# Cooresponding CopyResource method in D3D9

Tags: graphics, directx, direct3d9, direct3d10

I know it's easy to copy vertex/index buffer in D3D10 with 
IDirect3D10::CopyResource(...)
interface.

How to do the same work in D3D9? Is there any similar API for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just lock the vertex/index buffers and memcpy the data from one to the other.

Comment: I want to avoid Lock method, since Lock will create memory buffer internally, and it could be out of memory.
I wish I could reserved a buffer at beginning, and copy the target buffer to reserved buffer when mapping.

Comment: There is no other way to do it under DX9.  If you want to avoid running out of memory remember that you can lock a buffer a bit at a time so you can keep memory usage manageable.

Comment: I was under the impression that locking a dynamic buffer essentially mapped the existing memory for that buffer into your process, so locking a buffer doesn't actually use any additional memory as such.